# Duplicate email entries in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm doing my first project and it requires Stripe for recurring/subscription payments. I'm just starting and the approach I'm taking is that once the user registers, my Register controller creates the Stripe Customer profile as soon as user is created and stores the customer id to my User model.

While in my DB I don't allow multiple entries for the same email, it came to my attention that with Stripe this is not set up automatically and you can actually create multiple Stripe customers with the same email.

Should I allow this? or is it best to check for current stripe customers with that same email and block multiple entries?

Comment: Depends entirely on your integration and business model. Stripe doesn't make any assumptions on how you want to handle multiple customers with the email (or not), so the implementation is left up to you. If you have a business that sells products, then making sure the customer is unique by email is probably a good idea. If you're a business that sells subscriptions at multiple tiers, then perhaps having multiple customers is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for that I find it very helpful! Just curious about why would I set it up with multiple customers for subscriptions. My business model is actually subscriptions and I was thinking on just adding multiple plans options instead. Is that a good approach or how would you go about it?